# Check that value exists in a Generic List of Values

Tags: c#, generic-list

I am trying to figure out how to check if testInt exists in all Car.SomeID in List

So:

```
int testInt = 10;
List<Car> myCars = GetCars();
```

I want to see if there is a match on 10 in any of myCards.SomeID

Answer (score 17):

In the more general case, with LINQ (supports any type of abstract typed list):

```
bool hasCar = myCars.Any(c => c.SomeID == testInt);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
myCars.Exists(c => c.SomeID == 10);
```