# Is there a way that I can avoid an if statement full of checks

Tags: c#

My code looks like this:

```
 if (Settings.cc == CC.F1 || Settings.cc == CC.F2)
```

with additional tests for F3, F4 and F5

is there any way that I can avoid checking against Settings.cc for every entry?

Comment: Maybe what you need is to create a list of the values to check for. Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1848285/194717

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
if (new[] {CC.F1, CC.F2, CC.F3, CC.F4, CC.F5}.Contains(Settings.cc))
```

Comment: and likely put that new[] up into a const array.

Comment: Yes - new up the array at the highest scope that makes sense so you only recreate it when needed.

Comment: Also consider using a `HashSet` if there are a large number of entries.

Comment: @kenny - can you give an example

Comment: `public readonly CC[] MatchingCC = new [] { CC.F1, CC.F2, CC.F3, CC.F4, CC.F5 };`

Answer (score 2):

A [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) statement would certainly make it look clearer. Something like this.

```
switch (Settings.cc)
{
    case CC.F1:
      // Conditional code
      break;
    case CC.F2:
      // Conditional code
      break;
    default:
      Console.WriteLine("Default case");
      break;
}
```